# Manipulate reg expression variables in .htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, joomla

I want to redirect the client from

`http://mydomaine/cat?start=x`

to

`http://mydomaine/cat/page-(x divide by 15)`

e.g  from `http://mydomaine/cat?start=30`

to

`http://mydomaine/cat/page-2`

There any way to do that with .htaccess?

Comment: AFAIK htaccess file can't handle math operations. Is there any reason why you don't want to use the [`header()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function to redirect user from within the index page?

Comment: I'm not sure if I can avoid redirection loop with `header()` because on `haccess` I can use [L] flag.

Comment: Since you can't make calculations in htaccess it seems you will need to stick with PHP. But why do you think it will loop, isn't all you need `<?php $page = 1; if (preg_match('~\^d+$~',$_GET['start'])) $page = ceil($_GET['start'] / 15); header("Location: /page-{$page}"); ?>` in your index page?

Comment: Yes, in the reality I didn't thought to match about this solution; but it seems to work. I tried this code `$start = JRequest::getVar("start");
if( preg_match("/(.*)\?start=[0-9]+/", JRequest::getURI(),$matches ) ){ 
 header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', false, 301); 
 Header( "Location: ".$matches[1]."/page-".($start/15+1 ) );
 exit();
}`

Comment: Write this as an answer to this question and mark it as the working solution so that others can benefit from it as well ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all of you, so this the solution that is working for me:

```
if (preg_match("/(.*)\?limitstart=[0-9]+/", JRequest::getURI(), $matches)) {
    header('Status: 301 Moved Permanently', false, 301);
    header("Location: ".$matches[1]);
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure you can do this in .htacces file.

But, if you are under Joomla (from the tag of your question) you can create a **system plugin** which will let you manipulate urls.

Here is the doc from joomla.org [Documentation](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_System_Plugin_to_augment_JRouter)

I think this tip only work with joomla 2.5.

Comment: Yes I have joomla 2.5, but do you think the plug-in will help me to generate 301 redirect?